# How to randomize two UITextField variables?

Tags: objective-c, random, uitextfield

I have two textFields where the user types into some words.

Then, when pressing a button, i want the words to randomize and then the user displays the randomized result.

I have this code:

```
-(IBAction) randomInp{

    NSString *first = firstField.text;
    NSString *second = secondField.text;

    NSString *result = //here it should randomize the words
    //Display randomized word
    textview.text    = //should display result
}
```

where firstField and secondField are respectively the first and the second UITextFields. Then i don't know how to proceed!

I was thinking of set a switch condition. If it's 0 then returns *first, if it's 1 then returns *second. Am i right?

Any help appreciated

**EDIT**

Solved!

If anyone needs:

```
    -(IBAction) randomInp{

    NSString *first = firstField.text;
    NSString *second = secondField.text;
    int text = rand() % 2;
    switch (text) {
        case 0:
            textview.text = first;
            break;
        case 1:
            textview.text = second;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

The answer that SSteve gave works great, too! For anyone who needs:

```
NSString *result = random() & 1 ? first : second;
```

Comment: What do you mean for randomized word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To choose between two values you can use `random()` and check the value of a bit:

```
NSString *result = random() & 1 ? first : second;
```

Put a call to srandomdev() somewhere in your initialization code to avoid having the same sequence of values every time your program runs. You may also need `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: Two notes: 1) `random()` gives a better random sequence of bits than `rand()`, but since you aren't doing cryptographic stuff that probably doesn't matter. 2) Testing a bit is a lot faster than `% 2` but since you're working at the speed of user input that probably doesn't matter either. But keep those in mind for future purposes.

Comment: Sure, thank you! I may try your snippet and check what's better to use. Thanks btw! :)